# Multi selectable checkbox groups using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, checkboxlist

Some time back I was looking for multi select checkbox group option in angularjs. I could not able to find my self on stackoverflow, Since i have developed it and sharing here js fiddle link.

```
<div ng-app="check">
<div ng-controller="controller">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(key, item) in basket"> {{item.type}}
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="(sub_catkey, sub_catval) in item.fields">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" ng-model="sub_catval.checked" /> {{sub_catval.name}}  -- {{sub_catval.checked}} | json
            </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

</ul>
Selected show here
<li ng-repeat="(key, item) in basket"> {{item.type}}
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(sub_catkey, sub_catval) in item.fields | filter: true">
      <label>
        {{sub_catval.name}}  -- {{sub_catval.checked}}
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </li>
    {Manager: {Name: filter.key}}
    {{basket}}
```

angular.module('check', [])
    .controller('controller', function($scope) {

```
        $scope.basket = [
        {
        "type": "fruits",
        "fields": [
            {name: 'Apple', checked:false},
          {name: 'Mango', checked:true},
          {name: 'Banana', checked:false},
          {name: 'Guava', checked:false},
          {name: 'Orange', checked:false}
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "flowers",
        "fields": [
            {name: 'rose', checked:true},
          {name: 'lilly', checked:false},
          {name: 'tulip', checked:false},
          {name: 'marigold', checked:false},
          {name: 'sunflower', checked:false}
        ]
      }
    ];

    $scope.selected = {
        fruits: ["Apple"],
        flowers: []
    };



     $scope.checkAll = function() {
         $scope.basket = angular.copy($scope.basket);
      };
      $scope.uncheckAll = function() {
          $scope.selected.fruits = [];
      };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/42y83eLb/

Comment: To comply with the SO format, you should have asked a question, then answered it your self. Then you would get points for the question AND the answer ;-)

Comment: I am afraid it is not the place to share your code...